# Configuring default user in spring security

Tags: spring-security, jetty, embedded-jetty

is there a way  to configure spring security to have a default user (with roles and such)? i want to use it for testing purposes in an embedded jetty environment.

i provided an InMemoryUserDetailsService but i am missing the part where i tell spring security to use which user.

thanks for your help

fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean an anonymous user?

If so, try this: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html

> ("Spring Security's anonymous authentication just gives you a more
>   convenient way to configure your access-control attributes")

Comment: hm i haven't meant anonymous user, but since i can give the anonymous user roles for testing, its everything i need :)